# Shape Markers in Line Charts

Tags: image-charts

Is there a way to set Shape Markers in a Line Chart?

Google Image Charts to this with the `chm` attribute.

[For Example,](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=700x300&chd=t:1,2,3,4,5,6&chds=0,30&chxt=x,y&chxr=1,0,30&chxl=0:%7CA%7CB%7CC%7CD%7CE%7CF&chdl=LineChart&chdlp=t&chbh=85,30,0&chxs=0,000000,12&chco=FF0000&chm=D,00FF00,1,-1,2,1%7Co,FF0000,0,-1,15.0%7Cd,00FF00,1,-1,10.0)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently Image-Charts do not support this feature however if the only shape you need is the one from the example, [take a subscription](https://www.image-charts.com/) and contact our support, the feature will be priorized and implemented in the next weeks